# Kibana[5.3.0] - Index management in Bulk

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have ELK, that generates many different indexes. And in Kibana, I have over 50 indexes. They are dynamic. I would need some method to BULK this operation. And in general, how can I approach this programatically? I am interested in managing all those indexes that get created. Right now, I am adding new indexes in Kibana manually, which is error prone process.